How to use self signed client certificates in ddev
I created a CA solely for issuing self signed certificates that http clients should use to communicate with several rest endpoints of our application developed in a ddev environment using apache. I don't need or want to use my custom CA for TLS.
My intent was to add the CA via SSLCACertificateFile and use SSLVerifyClient optional with SSLOptions +StdEnvVars to evaluate the certificate in the relevant routes.
I can't figure out, how to approach this challenge. The extracted .ddev/apache/apache-site.conf contains a VirtualHost block for :80 and a :443 block, but the code inside the :443 block doesn't seem to get executed at all. Adding SetEnv FOO "1" to the :80 block get's passed to application, but adding it to the :443 block never will. I assume, that the ddev-router is terminating the ssl connection of the http clients and the ddev-router is communicating via http with the ddev project.
So if it is possible to achieve the client certificate validation goal in a ddev project using apache, can anybody tell me how?

DDEV provides certs for all projects and serves via HTTPS, and you don't need to do anything to get that feature. It works via mkcert, which provides a CA for DDEV.
Because the ddev-router does termination of HTTPS, you wouldn't install a custom cert in Apache anyway, because then other components of the docker ecosystem wouldn't be able to trust it.
If you actually want to use your own self-signed or custom certificates, the DDEV Documentation on Custom Certificates tells how to do it.
